# Animation only plays for me but not for other players

Tags: roblox

I have a script(local script)that plays an animation whenever the tool is equipped and stops when the tool is not equipped, i got almost all of it right except the animation does not replicate to other players.

Script:

```
local tool = script.Parent.Parent
local anim = script.Parent:WaitForChild("RaiseArms")
local track

tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
track = tool.Parent.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(anim)
track.Looped = true
track.Priority = Enum.AnimationPriority.Action
track:Play()

tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    track:Stop()
end)
end)
```

Comment: Nvm i fixed it, turns out the track.Priority part is the one that's causing the animation to not replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the local script for a script and paste the same code in it. Place the script in the same location you placed the local script.

Here is a note from the API reference about animations:
If an Animator is a descendant of a Humanoid or AnimationController in a Player’s Character then animations started on that Player’s client will be replicated to the server and other clients.
If the Animator is not a descendant of a player character, its animations must be loaded and started on the server to replicate.

Link: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Animation

Comment: So in order for my animation to replicate to other players, i gotta use Animator:LoadAnimation ?

Comment: And also i did put it in a server script and it worked but when i walked or jumped the animation stopped